# How can I work with OLE2 objects in Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I am working on a python project where I need to read an *xlsx*, edit a row on a specific worksheet and then save it to run a bigger program in Anylogic (the *xlsx* file is an input for this program). The thing is that I can not modify the Anylogic program (it's an exported program) and I get the following error:

```
Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream
```

I tried using Pandas to modify the *xlsx* and then I tried to use `openpyxl` which is the library that Pandas uses to work with *xlsx* and *xls* files.

Here's the code I used with `openpyxl`

```py
def open_workbook(source_file: str, worksheet_name: str):
 
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(source_file)
    worksheet = workbook.worksheets[WORKSHEETS_NAME[worksheet_name]]
    

    return workbook, worksheet
    

def write_extreme(workbook, worksheet_name: str, j: int):
    
    worksheet = workbook.worksheets[WORKSHEETS_NAME[worksheet_name]]

    for i in range(worksheet.max_row - 1):
        if i == j:
            print("hola")
            worksheet.cell(i + 1, CA_COLUMNS_INDEX["nAmbulance"], 1771)
            print(1771 - worksheet.max_row + 2)
        else:
            print("hola2")
            worksheet.cell(i + 1, CA_COLUMNS_INDEX["nAmbulance"], 1)
 

    workbook.save(SOURCE_PATH + "Hospitales_Ambulancias_CM_3.xlsx")
```

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off with Xlwings (if you are using windows with a local copy of Excel) since its like using VBA in python and can manage OLE. However not familiar with  Anylogic so can't comment any further.

Comment: It actually solves the problem for me. But you need to have excel installed and can not work in linux.